# Flutter Radio Button not changing value when clicked/ Not changing active color either

Tags: flutter, dart

I've tried following tutorials for the Radio class in flutter however the button isn't changing color when I click on it. I know that the device is reading the clicks because I put a print statement to display whenever the button is clicked but the button color isn't changing.

I just don't know what the problem is

```
int radioValue = -1;

void _handleRadioValueChanged (int value){
  setState(() {
    radioValue = value;
    print(radioValue);
  });
}

return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Radio<int>(
                activeColor: Colors.green,
                value: 0,
                groupValue: radioValue,
                onChanged: _handleRadioValueChanged),

        new Radio<int>(
            activeColor: Colors.green,
            value: 1,
            groupValue: radioValue,
            onChanged: _handleRadioValueChanged),

        new Radio <int>(
            activeColor: Colors.green,
            value: 2,
            groupValue: radioValue,
            onChanged: _handleRadioValueChanged),

    ),
  )
);
```

I expect the button to change when pressed but it just remains in a state of value =-1;

Comment: It work fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int radioValue = -1;

  void _handleRadioValueChanged(int value) {
    setState(() {
      radioValue = value;
      print(radioValue);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: new Center(
      child: new Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
        new Radio(
            activeColor: Colors.green,
            value: 0,
            groupValue: radioValue,
            onChanged: _handleRadioValueChanged),
        new Radio<int>(
            activeColor: Colors.green,
            value: 1,
            groupValue: radioValue,
            onChanged: _handleRadioValueChanged),
        new Radio<int>(
            activeColor: Colors.green,
            value: 2,
            groupValue: radioValue,
            onChanged: _handleRadioValueChanged),
      ]),
    ));
  }
}
```

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLVAz.gif)

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same code as the original question? I'm confused.

Comment: The code is same, just he had forgotten to put a "]" at the end. So he may be getting the error.

Comment: The code wouldn't even compile if there was a missing bracket. It's probably just a copy-paste error.

Comment: still have the problem, I have no clue what i'm doing wrong but i'll probably just avoid using radio buttons for a while till i can figure it out.

Comment: So i copied and pasted his code and it worked! I don't know what I did wrong - it wasn't a compile error, I'll try to figure it out

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I didn't put the function above the @override

Comment: it wasn't me :( i tried to upvote but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Sorry about that

Comment: Thanks man i appreciate it, maybe advance users some time misuse their powers